# FileMaker - How to query multiple database files via ODBC

Tags: c#, odbc, filemaker

When I use ODBC to query a FileMaker 11 server, it looks like my query is restricted to retrieve data from one database at a time.

I want to query for data in one database, but only return records that have some related data in another database (on the same FileMaker server). I know how to write normal JOINs, but I don't know *how to do this across multiple databases*.

Is this even possible? If so, can you please provide a small SQL Query example or code snippet (preferably in C#)?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Internally in FileMaker, to run ExecuteSQL (available from FMP 12) on a table from a different file you would need to add a Table Occurrence of it to Relationships in Manage Database. Try this, if it does not work you might need to query both DNS separately and join results inside your code.

Comment: Thanks @nicolai.kant. Clear comment. I will give that a try. Can't test it before monday/tuesday, but I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: @nicolai.kant Finally found some time to test it. Querying the Table Occurence works great via ODBC. If you register your suggestion as 'Answer', I can mark it as the answer and you'll get your well-deserved reputation credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker ODBC queries, same as ExecuteSQL (FQL) statements are based on a Table Occurrence placed in the relationships graph of "Manage Database".

To use a table from another FileMaker file (database, DSN) in a query, add this file to the "External Data Sources" of the target file and place the Table Occurrence of the table you need to query into "Manage Database" of the target file.

This was just a guess initially, but was kindly confirmed by @Maarten Docter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know filemaker but if it accepts plain SQL you **can** join data across databases (given that they run on the same database server). Just refer the full path to your columns. For example if you want to join serial numbers of database A B and C:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM DatabaseA.dbo.MainDb
    INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.SubDb ON DatabaseA.dbo.MainDb.Serialnumber = DatabaseB.dbo.SubDb.Serialnumber
    INNER JOIN DatabaseC.dbo.Other ON DatabaseA.dbo.MainDb.Serialnumber = DatabaseC.dbo.Other.Serialnumber
```

note that if you want a specific set of columns, you have to write the full path of said column (same way as shown in the join)

Comment: Thanks Nick Otten, but this won't work. I know this query construction from SQL Server, but when I use a User or System DSN (ODBC) to FileMaker or specifiy a connection string in my C# code, I'll always have to specify a database name. So the query is restricted to that database. The 'Table Occurence' mentioned by @nicolai.kant above, hopefully does the trick, but I have to test it.